# displaying Oracle table's column names

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a one-liner out there for this task? Note that I won't be using Oracle's SQL Plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: I choose this due to greater simplicity.

Comment: Yes. Aliases are to resolve ambiguities and not to add noise everywhere

Comment: What you see as greater simplicity now is true... but eventually this simple query will grow. You may want to know if the column is part of the key, for example, and you'll have to join this to another table. Once you have a second table in the query EVERY column should have the alias as part of the query whether the optimizer requires it or not. So why not just get in the habit now?

Answer (score 8):

This statement will select all the columns for a table, just replace 'TABLE_NAME' with the actual name of the table.  Keep in mind that the tables names are uppercase.

```
select utc.column_name 
  from user_tab_columns utc
 where utc.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
 order by utc.COLUMN_ID
```

Comment: utc is just an alias for the table name.  The SQL program I use has something like intellisence so it pops up column names after the dot.  It's just a habit of mine from using the software.  And I ordered the columns just so that they appear in the same order that they are declared in the table.  Your answer does provide the same information.